# I want to Group questions and answers LINQ and have them display properly

Tags: linq, html-table

I'm trying to group properly to have my cell distribute eveningly. The printout is coming very odd and uneven.

is it the table i'm creating or group or both? I think the group is correct. My results are as shown in the image below.

Gold is the heading,
Green are the questions,
Red are the answers

[image]

[image]

Mt table is is below

```
var Sections = new OncologySection().SelectSections(projectID.ToString());
        int iSection = 0;
        int igroups = 0;
        int ianswer = 0;

        tb.CssClass = "";
        tb.BorderWidth = 1;
        tb.Width = new Unit("780px");
        tb.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

        foreach (OncologySection section in Sections)
        {
            TableRow row1 = new TableRow();
            iSection++;
                            // var getDistinctQuestion = getVoterAnswerstoList.Select(s => s.QuestionText ,s.Id).Distinct().ToList();

            var getVoterAnswerstoList = new OncologyGeneratePDFDAL().DataforPDFCreation(Convert.ToInt32(projectID), Convert.ToInt32(voterid), Convert.ToInt32(caseId), Convert.ToInt32(voteSurveyId), Convert.ToInt32(section.SectionID)).OrderBy(os => os.SortOrder);

            //var groupedCustomerList = getVoterAnswerstoList
            //    .GroupBy(u => u.QuestionText, u.QuestionText)
            //    .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
            //    .ToList();

            var groupedCustomerList = getVoterAnswerstoList.GroupBy(x => new { x.QuestionText, x.DynamicValue }).ToList();


            TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
            cell1.BorderWidth = 1;
            cell1.Text = section.SectionName;
            cell1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Goldenrod;
            cell1.ColumnSpan = groupedCustomerList.Count();
            row1.Cells.Add(cell1);
            tb.Rows.Add(row1);


            TableRow row2 = new TableRow();

            foreach (var groups in groupedCustomerList)
            {
                igroups++;

                TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();

                var q = (from s in groups select s.QuestionText).FirstOrDefault();
                cell2.BorderWidth = 1;
                cell2.Text = q;
                cell2.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                cell2.ColumnSpan = groupedCustomerList.Count();
                row2.Cells.Add(cell2);


                if (igroups == groupedCustomerList.Count())
                {
                    tb.Rows.Add(row2);
                }
                else
                {
                    row2.Cells.Add(cell2);
                }
                TableRow row3 = new TableRow();
                foreach (var answers in groups)
                {

                    ianswer++;

                    TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();

                    cell3.BorderWidth = 1;

                    cell3.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;
                    if (answers.DataTypeId == 7)
                    {
                        cell3.Text = answers.DynamicValue.ToString();
                    }
                    else if ((answers.DataTypeId == 5) || (answers.DataTypeId == 6) || (answers.DataTypeId == 8))
                    {

                        if (answers.VotingValue != 0)
                        {
                            cell3.Text = answers.VotingValue.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cell3.Text = "&nbsp;";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        cell3.Text = "&nbsp;";
                    }

                    row3.Cells.Add(cell3);
                    tb.Rows.Add(row3);
                }

            }

        } 

    }
```

Comment: Can you please write down the expected output?

Comment: There is a lot of bad and peculiar logic in this code. Why is `igroups` reset at a different level from `groupedCustomerList`. Why are you counting in a `foreach`? Why are you adding `cell` to `row2.Cells` twice?